# certain node.js Express endpoints working locally but not in production

Tags: node.js, express

I am running into a frustrating issue where certain end points refuse to work (giving 404 errors) whenever I push my code to the production backend vs my localhost.  I have completely remade the endpoints and created a new router but nothing seems to work. 99% of the endpoints work besides any new one I try to make.  Here is my code:

```
app.use(helmet())
app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({api: 'upupup'})
})
app.use('/users', cors({origin:'*'}), checkAuthToken, userRouter.route)
app.use('/fund', cors({origin:'*'}), checkAuthToken, fundRouter.route)
app.use('/auth', cors({origin:'*'}),  authRouter.route)
app.use('/crypto', cors({origin:'*'}), cryptoRouter.route)
app.use('/pool', poolRouter.route)
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Every router works besides certain endpoints within.  I tried creating a new "pool" router but that didn't fix the issue.  Here is the "pool" router:

```
const express = require('express')

const {getSingleUserPoolData, getSingleUserPoolDataTest} = require('../controllers/f2poolController')

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/pooldata', getSingleUserPoolData)
router.get('/pooldata', getSingleUserPoolDataTest)


module.exports = {
    route:router
}
```

And here is the endpoint in question:

```
const getSingleUserPoolDataTest = async (req, res) => {
    try{

        const userID = req.params.id
        const poolUserData = await getMinerUserDataByID(userID)
        if(poolUserData){
            const poolID = poolUserData.id
            const l7Percentage = poolUserData.minerPercentages.L7
            axios.get(`${poolURL}/litecoin/${poolID}`)
            .then(data => {
                const currentHashrate = data.data.hashrate * l7Percentage
         
            let formattedHashData = []
            for (var key in historicHashrates){
                let formattedNumbers = historicHashrates[key] * l7Percentage
                formattedHashData.push({"date":key, "hashrate":formattedNumbers})
            }
            const workers = {
                name:data.data.workers[0][0],
                hashrate:data.data.workers[0][1] * l7Percentage,
                hashrate_1h:data.data.workers[0][2] * l7Percentage,
                hashrate_24h:data.data.workers[0][4] * l7Percentage,
                stale_24h:data.data.workers[0][5] * l7Percentage,
                recent_shares:data.data.workers[0][6] * l7Percentage,
                extra:data.data.workers[0][7],
                historic_hashrate:formattedHashData.slice(-31),
                currenthashrate:currentHashrate
            }
            
            const returnData = [
                workers
            ]
            
            res.status(200).send(returnData)
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(401).json({message:"something went wrongo"}))
    }
    else {
        return res.status(400).json({message:"error finding poolID"})
    }
}
catch(err){
    res.status(400).json({err})
}

}
```

No idea why I am always getting a "404" error when hitting that endpoint so I created another test one and had the exact same issue:

```
const testEndpoint = async (req, res) => {
    try{
        let id = req.params.id
        res.status(200).send(id)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getSingleUserPoolData,
    getSingleUserPoolDataTest,
    testEndpoint
}
```

I am open to any suggestions (i'm probably being an idiot) and thank you for reading this.

Comment: Probably URL is wrong

Comment: I don't think the URL is wrong, I have tried triple checking many different end points and they all work fine on localhost but not on hosted.  All the other end points work on hosted so the base URL isn't the issue either. Including testing with Postman

Comment: what is `poolURL`? where is the endpoint for `/litecoin/:id`?

Comment: poolURL is a placeholder for a separate 3rd party API that I am calling to get information to send to my client on the front end.  the /litecoin/:id is part of that 3rd party API call.  Apologies for not making that clearer.